# AJAX Callbacks Allowing HTML

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a comment form on my website and I would like to stop any HTML from being posted through it. I was under the impression that ASP.NET automatically stops any HTML from being submitted by throwing a "potentially dangerous request" exception, but it's allowing HTML in this case.

All of the settings that relate to validation have been left to default so it should be set to `requestValidationMode="4.0"`.

Anyone know what can cause this? Does it have anything to do with the fact that I am using AJAX callbacks?

Edit: I have gathered some more details:

Validation is correctly working in one sub-folder in my application, but it isn't working in any of the others. I looked into my web.config and this is the only setting I have put regarding page validation:

```
<pages enableViewStateMac="true" validateRequest="true">
```

Why is it working in one subfolder but not in the others? Does it have anything to do with the fact that this subfolder has a web.config entry regarding authentication?

Edit: Regular postbacks are being validated, just not callbacks.

Edit again: I was playing around with Fiddler and while doing so I noticed one of the callbacks was blocked by the server. Here is what the blocked request looks like:

And here is the plain text version:

[image: Good Request]

```
__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%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%2BCjwvc2NyaXB0Pgo8c2NyaXB0IHR5cGU9InRleHQvamF2YXNjcmlwdCIKc3JjPSJodHRwOi8vcGFnZWFkMi5nb29nbGVzeW5kaWNhdGlvbi5jb20vcGFnZWFkL3Nob3dfYWRzLmpzIj4KPC9zY3JpcHQ%2BZAIDDxYCHwIFqgI8c2NyaXB0IHR5cGU9InRleHQvamF2YXNjcmlwdCI%2BPCEtLQpnb29nbGVfYWRfY2xpZW50ID0gImNhLXB1Yi05NjEzNjkwNDkwNTI4ODE0IjsKLyogQk9JRyBTaWRlYmFyICovCmdvb2dsZV9hZF9zbG90ID0gIjIyMDAxMDYxMTAiOwpnb29nbGVfYWRfd2lkdGggPSAxNjA7Cmdvb2dsZV9hZF9oZWlnaHQgPSA2MDA7Ci8vLS0%2BCjwvc2NyaXB0Pgo8c2NyaXB0IHR5cGU9InRleHQvamF2YXNjcmlwdCIKc3JjPSJodHRwOi8vcGFnZWFkMi5nb29nbGVzeW5kaWNhdGlvbi5jb20vcGFnZWFkL3Nob3dfYWRzLmpzIj4KPC9zY3JpcHQ%2BZAIEDw8WAh4HVmlzaWJsZWdkZAIFDxYCHwIFEjxwPkxpbmsgMSB0ZXh0PC9wPmQCBg9kFgICAw8WAh8DaGQCBw8WAh4EVGV4dAU%2BPHNwYW4gc3R5bGU9Im1hcmdpbi1yaWdodDogNXB4OyI%2BwqkgQmluZGluZ09mSXNhYWNHdWlkZTwvc3Bhbj5kZKMbP1fMlxWhgVw8zpEPBPGzlw5j&=sdfdsgd%40sfds.com&=%3Cp%3Efghfghfg%3C%2Fp%3E&=%3Cp%3Efghfghfg%3C%2Fp%3E&=%3Cp%3Efghfghfg%3C%2Fp%3E&__CALLBACKID=__Page&__CALLBACKPARAM=sdfdsgd%40sfds.com--%7C%7C--%3Cp%3Efghfghfg%3C%2Fp%3E--%7C%7C--%3Cp%3Efghfghfg%3C%2Fp%3E--%7C%7C--%3Cp%3Efghfghfg%3C%2Fp%3E
```

Here is a typical request that isn't blocked:

Plain text:

[image: Bad Request]

```
__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%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%2BCjwvc2NyaXB0Pgo8c2NyaXB0IHR5cGU9InRleHQvamF2YXNjcmlwdCIKc3JjPSJodHRwOi8vcGFnZWFkMi5nb29nbGVzeW5kaWNhdGlvbi5jb20vcGFnZWFkL3Nob3dfYWRzLmpzIj4KPC9zY3JpcHQ%2BZAIDDxYCHwIFqgI8c2NyaXB0IHR5cGU9InRleHQvamF2YXNjcmlwdCI%2BPCEtLQpnb29nbGVfYWRfY2xpZW50ID0gImNhLXB1Yi05NjEzNjkwNDkwNTI4ODE0IjsKLyogQk9JRyBTaWRlYmFyICovCmdvb2dsZV9hZF9zbG90ID0gIjIyMDAxMDYxMTAiOwpnb29nbGVfYWRfd2lkdGggPSAxNjA7Cmdvb2dsZV9hZF9oZWlnaHQgPSA2MDA7Ci8vLS0%2BCjwvc2NyaXB0Pgo8c2NyaXB0IHR5cGU9InRleHQvamF2YXNjcmlwdCIKc3JjPSJodHRwOi8vcGFnZWFkMi5nb29nbGVzeW5kaWNhdGlvbi5jb20vcGFnZWFkL3Nob3dfYWRzLmpzIj4KPC9zY3JpcHQ%2BZAIEDw8WAh4HVmlzaWJsZWdkZAIFDxYCHwIFEjxwPkxpbmsgNSB0ZXh0PC9wPmQCBg9kFgICAw8WAh8DaGQCBw8WAh4EVGV4dAU%2BPHNwYW4gc3R5bGU9Im1hcmdpbi1yaWdodDogNXB4OyI%2BwqkgQmluZGluZ09mSXNhYWNHdWlkZTwvc3Bhbj5kZCu6t45MzsFLBRWYDAvPXYbIXKqE&=&=&=&=&__CALLBACKID=__Page&__CALLBACKPARAM=cfdsdg%40adfds.com--%7C%7C--%3Cp%3Esdfdgdfg%3C%2Fp%3E--%7C%7C--%3Cp%3Esdfdgdfg%3C%2Fp%3E--%7C%7C--%3Cp%3Esdfdgdfg%3C%2Fp%3E
```

I don't know why the requests are different, nothing changed on the page. I noticed that the first one seems to have split the parameters into the boxes while the second one hasn't. Is this the issue?

I just checked the callbacks being sent from the sub-folder and they are all split into parameters just like the first request. I guess this is the problem... but why is it happening?

I made the inputs `runat=server` and the request changed a bit, but the values are still not being assigned.

[image: Semi-Good Req]

Comment: Can you post some sample code here, if you are using @Html.Action then it suppose to render the View that you are calling. If you want to allow html you can always use AllowHtml=True data attribute in you controller to allow html. Without seeing your code this is the best I can do.

Comment: The following doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339.aspx seems to indicate that you also need `<pages validateRequest="true" />` in the `<system.web>` section of your `web.config'.  Can you check this setting and report back?

Comment: Hi guys, this problem is really strange. Some pages are validating correctly, and some are not. I will update the main question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found:

___CALLBACKPARAM is not actually validated by the server, only the parameters as seen in the first image are. With this in mind I validated the request myself using the following regex `<\/*(p|div|span|a|script|br|b|i|u|h1|h2|h3|ol|ul|li)\s*.*>`. You can find more online; hope this helps.